# Ubuntu 16.04 USB stick would show me the same performance as the physical computer?

Tags: usb-drive, performance

I have a brand new computer Lenovo Y700, that came with win10 home.

Before to take the decision of wipe out windows and install Linux forever,  I would like to test all the machine resources ( all 8 cpu, 16Gb run, etc ) running Ubuntu 16.04 in a bootable USB stick and perform some tests before to decide.

But my question now is:

If I run Ubuntu form a USB stick, would I or could I say that the result of performance tests would be the same as if the Linux where installed in the physical machine?  Can I trust on this result 100% as it was running from the computer itself.

Note: The performance test I intend to run is - load a 5Gb database in a MariaDB-server and run some CRUD syntaxes.

Comment: Do the Ubuntu install just pick option to install along side existing OS this will keep your win10 intact ... then on boot pick which OS ... this gives you unquestioned speed then later just do re-install doing full wipe after testing

Comment: In my experience running from the live USB has much poorer performance than running from a real install.